# list in multiple lines and index is of float64 type

Tags: python

I am stuck here and can not go further because the list of distances are output like this: (it is said to be a list with length of 3, but printed out in multiple lines). I want to get the index of the smallest numbers of each list, so I can get a list of index like [1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0.....]; but I can't navigate with a list of multiple lines like this. Pls help. Thank you
[image]

Comment: Please share a minimum working example (MWE) so that we can adress your question. See how to create a MW here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: please show the code, especially how this list is defined

Comment: what you have is a list of lists. The outer list is length 3, and each of the inner lists is also length 3.

Answer (score 0):

To get indices of minimal values of each sublist, you can combine `enumerate()` and `zip()` builtin functions. For example:

```
lst = [
    [5, 4, 3],
    [4, 4, 2],
    [4, 3, 2]
]

indices = []
for sublist in lst:
    indices.append( min(enumerate(sublist), key=lambda k: k[1])[0] )

print(indices)
```

Prints:

```
[2, 2, 2]
```

---

List-comprehension version:

```
indices = [min(enumerate(sublist), key=lambda k: k[1])[0] for sublist in lst]
```

Comment: it said "numpy.float64' object is not iterable"

Comment: @user14416085 That means you have something different in `lst`. Not list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of min element in a list using

```
a = [1,2,3]
i = a.index(min(a))
print(i)
```

For your particular example -

```
ans = []
l = [
    [5, 4, 3],
    [4, 4, 2],
    [4, 3, 2]
]

for i in l:
   ans.append(i.index(min(i)))
print(ans)
```

Comment: it does not work for me because the "i" here iterates over the elements of whole list in vertical direction, like 5 4 4 or 4 4 3 or 3 2 2, also the output is of float64 type, so I can not assign the indexes to them,

Comment: @user14416085 Please share a minimum working example (MWE). The question seems a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your input as an array of lists(2D array), You can use this function:

```
def example(any_2d_list):  # add only 2d array list to get input
    index_list = []  # the list with indexes you want
    for group in any_2d_list:
        index_list.append(group.index(min(group)))  # adds indexes to the list 
    print(index_list)
```